# Rotation, Enlargement about $ (x,y) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I see this a lot in questions but I've never taken the time to figure what it means when a questions says "about $(x,y)$".

For example, what does a rotation about $(0,0) $ mean?

Also, what does an Enlargement about $(0,0)$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rotation, enlargement about Q(x,y)]

Suppose that $Q$ is a point with coordinates $(x,y)$ and $P$ is any other point in the plane.

What does it mean to say that $P$ is rotated about $Q(x,y)$ by an angle $\theta$?

To understand this, draw the circle centered at $Q(x,y)$ and containing the point $P$. Rotate the circle about $Q$ through an angle $\theta$ just as one would rotate a wheel about a hub. This rotation will move the point $P$ to a different point $P^\prime$. Recall that angles may be positive or negative and that a positive angle represents a counter-clockwise rotatin and a negative angle represents a clockwise rotation.

Now suppose that the point $P$ is changed (enlarged or shrunk) by a factor of $m$ about $Q(x,y)$. If $m>1$ then it will be *enlarged* meaning that it will lie further from $Q$ than it was originally. If $0<m<1$ then it will be *shrunk* meaning that it will be closer to $Q$.

In the diagram it is assumed that $m>1$. If $P$ is expanded by a factor of $m$ with respect to $Q(x,y)$ then $P$ is moved to the point $P^{\prime\prime}$ lying on the ray $QP$ a distance of $m\vert QP\vert$ from $Q(x,y)$ where $\vert QP\vert$ is the distance from $Q(x,y)$ to $P$.

Answer (score 0):

If a point $A$ is rotated by an angle $\theta$ about $P=(x,y)$ to give $A'$, then $\langle APA' = \theta$ and $|AP|=|A'P|$.

Similarly, if a point $A$ is enlarged by a factor $k$ about $P=(x,y)$ to give $A'$, then $|A'P|=k|AP|$ and $A$, $P$, and $A'$ are collinear.